# Cannot connect to internet through DAP-1650

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, network-manager, broadcom

**Problem**

I cannot connect to the Internet when connected to my *DLink Wireless AC1200 Access Point DAP-1650* via Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr LTS.  I *can* connect to the Internet when connected to my *Netgear Broadband Router WNDR 3700 v3*, which unfortunately is further away in the basement through quite a number of walls.  Everything works when booted into Windows with both wireless networks.

This is a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr LTS, installed last week and updated via eth0, and has never worked.  I get an IP address assigned, I get the "Connected to " after connecting, but I cannot access anything on my local network or on the internet.

**Network**

```
- Comcast Blast 105 Cable Internet
- [Motorola Surfboard SB6121 DOCSIS 3.0][1]
- [Netgear Broadcom Router WNDR 3700 v3][2]
- [DLINK Wireless AC1200 Access Point][3], connected via Gigabit Ethernet to WNDR3700
```

**System**

```
- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS  3.13.0-45-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP (Dual Boot with Windows 7)
- Dell Inspiron N4010

$ lspci -nn -d 14e4:
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
```

---

```
$ iwconfig (working connection)
eth0      no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.
wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"NetgearWNDR3700v3"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 4C:60:DE:46:83:FB   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

---

```
$ iwconfig (Failed connection)
eth0      no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.
wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"DAP1650"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.457 GHz  Access Point: F8:E9:03:C9:E3:F0   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

---

```
$ dmesg (tailed after trying to connect to DAP-1650)
[ 5030.512332] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 5030.583870] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[ 5030.583875] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[ 5030.583877] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 5030.583878] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 5030.583880] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 5030.583881] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 5030.583883] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
```

---

Here is the output of lsmod:

```
$ lsmod |grep -e wl -e brcmsmac
wl                   4207846  0 
lib80211               14381  2 wl,lib80211_crypt_tkip
cfg80211              484040  1 wl
```

If I go to Settings->Software & Updates->Additional Drivers, there is an entry:
    Broadcom Corporation: Inspiron M5010/XPS 8300
    This device is using an alternate driver.
    Using Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source from bcmwl-kernel-source (proprietary)
    1 proprietary driver in use.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Which driver is in use? lsmod | grep -e wl -e brcmsmac Welcome to askubuntu!

Comment: @chili555, I added output from your command to the original question. Looks like it is lib80211, and bcmwl-kernel-source.

Comment: Please check here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/569360/slow-connection-with-14-04-in-a-wifi-network/571512#571512

Comment: **SUCCESS!**  I ran the three commands from the linked question (apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source; modprobe -r wl; modprobe brcmsmac) and can now access the Internet via the DAP-1650.  Now off to solve my java plugin problems...

Answer (score 1):

From @chili555's [linked answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569360/slow-connection-with-14-04-in-a-wifi-network/571512#571512), the `bcmwl-kernel-source` package isn't always the right driver for the 14e4:4727.

I ran these commands

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe -r wl
sudo modprobe brcmsmac
```

and my problem was fixed.